# How can I override a component registered in Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm just starting with Windsor, so please be gentle :) I have a scenario where I want to be able to override/replace components placed inside a windsor container. Read on ...

In my prod code, I want to be able to register a component which implements a base class, and use a container to resolve the implementer. So far, using

```
container.Register(Component.For<LoggerBase>().ImplementedBy<DebugLogger>());
```

and

```
container.Resolve<LoggerBase>();
```

In my tests, I'd like to add a stub/mock implementation to override the "DebugLogger" implementation so that when my prod code calls `container.Resolve<LoggerBase>();` it gets the overridden implementation.

Any pointers would be welcome!

Comment: Version 3 now implements the `IsDefault` member, allowing you to solve this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253388/in-castle-windsor-3-override-an-existing-component-registration/9254043#9254043

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of chasing down that path, you should rather use different container instances for different scenarios. Each instance could be configured differently. That's the whole point of a DI Container.

However, in general [DI Containers should not be used for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465849/using-ioc-for-unittesting/1465896#1465896).

Comment: Mark, thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't thought about that approach. The only downside I guess is if I have a large number of registrations in the container and you want to override a single component. This does however provide a good solution - thanks again!

Comment: If you need multiple containers that are almost identical, you can create derived containers and then use the Template Method design pattern to override their configurations where they differ.