# In Castle Windsor 3, override an existing component registration in a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, castle-windsor

I am attempting to use Castle Windsor in my automated tests like so:

On every test:

- The `Setup()` function creates a Windsor container, registering default implementations of each component
- The `Test` function access the components via the method `IWindsorContainer.Resolve<T>`, and tests their behavior
- The `TearDown()` function disposes of the Windsor container (and any created components)

For example, I might have 15 tests which accesses components which indirectly results in the creation of an `IMediaPlayerProxyFactory` component. The `SetUp` function registers a good-enough implementation `IMediaPlayerProxyFactory`, so I don't have the maintenance burden of registering this in each of the 15 tests.

However, I'm now writing a test `Test_MediaPlayerProxyFactoryThrowsException`, confirming my system elegantly handles an error from the `IMediaPlayerProxyFactory` component. In the test method I've created my special mock implementation, and now I want to inject it into the framework:

```c#
this.WindsorContainer.Register(
                                 Component.For<IMediaPlayerProxyFactory>()
                                          .Instance(mockMediaPlayerProxyFactory)
                              );
```

But Windsor throws a `Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException`, with the message "There is already a component with that name."

Is there any way that I can make my `mockMediaPlayerProxyFactory` be the default instance for the `IMediaPlayerProxyFactory`, discarding the component that's already registered?

---

According to the [documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx?NS=Windsor), Castle Windsor 3 allows for registration overrides, but I could only find one example:

```c#
Container.Register(
    Classes.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn<IEmptyService>()
        .WithService.Base()
        .ConfigureFor<EmptyServiceA>(c => c.IsDefault()));
```

`ConfigureFor` is a method of the `BasedOnDescriptor` class. In my case I'm not using the `FromDescriptor` or `BasedOnDescriptor`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are two things that you have to do to create an overriding instance:

1. Assign it a unique name
2. Call the `IsDefault` method

So to get the example to work:

```c#
this.WindsorContainer.Register(
   Component.For<IMediaPlayerProxyFactory>()
      .Instance(mockMediaPlayerProxyFactory)
      .IsDefault()
      .Named("OverridingFactory")
);
```

Because I plan to use this overriding patten in many tests, I've created my own extension method:

```c#
public static class TestWindsorExtensions
{
    public static ComponentRegistration<T> OverridesExistingRegistration<T>(
       this ComponentRegistration<T> componentRegistration
    ) where T : class
    {
        return componentRegistration
           .Named(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
           .IsDefault();
    }
}
```

Now the example can be simplified to:

```c#
this.WindsorContainer.Register(
   Component.For<IMediaPlayerProxyFactory>()
      .Instance(mockMediaPlayerProxyFactory)
      .OverridesExistingRegistration()
);
```

---

**Later Edit**

Version 3.1 introduces the `IsFallback` method. If I register all my initial components with `IsFallback`, then any new registrations will automatically override these initial registrations. I would have gone down that path if the functionality was available at the time.

https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/whats-new-3.1.md#fallback-components

Comment: naming and invoking `.IsDefault` method aren't required on the real implementation, other than that, very nice!

Comment: `IsFallback()` doesn't seem to work with `Func`. For example, adding `IsFallback()` to `container.Register(Component.For<Func<ICat>>().UsingFactoryMethod<Func<ICat>>(() => () => new Cat()));` does not prevent the duplicate key error if I override this registration later. However, adding `IsDefault().Named(Guid.New.ToString())` to the overriding registration works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reuse your container across tests. Instead, set it to `null` in the `TearDown()` and re-initialise it for each actual test.

Comment: Sorry, I mustn't have been clear. I do dispose of the container in the `TearDown()`, and I re-initialise it in the `SetUp()`. I'll change my intro to try and make that more explicit.