# Registering NUnit DynamicMock Instances in a UnityContainer

Tags: dependency-injection, nunit, mocking, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm somewhat new to Unity and dependency injection. I'm trying to write a unit test that goes something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    DynamicMock myMock = new DynamicMock(typeof(IMyInterface));
    container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IMyInterface), myMock.MockInstance);  //Error here

    // Continue unit test...
}
```

When this test executes, the container throws an ArgumentNullException inside the RegisterInstance method with the message `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: assignmentValueType.`

The top line of the stack trace is `at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Utility.Guard.TypeIsAssignable(Type assignmentTargetType, Type assignmentValueType, String argumentName)`.

Why can't I register a MockInstance with the UnityContainer, and how do I work around this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098937/proper-way-to-mock-repository-objects-for-unit-tests-using-moq-and-unity/2102104

Comment: Have you asked your question on the Unity Codeplex site?
http://unity.codeplex.com/ You might get an answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing this. I'm using [NUnit 2.5.5.10112](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download) and [Unity 2.0](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) (which ships with EntLib, the separate release isn't available just yet).

**Update:** I just checked with 1.2 and I see your behavior. So this is an issue with 1.2.

```
namespace UnityRepro
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        void Foo();
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact] 
        public void Test() 
        { 
            UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer(); 
            DynamicMock myMock = new DynamicMock(typeof(IMyInterface)); 
            container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IMyInterface), myMock.MockInstance);  //Error here 

            Assert.NotNull(container.Resolve<IMyInterface>());
        } 
    }
}
```

Would it be possible for you to update to Unity 2.0? If not I'll try and dig deeper and find out what's really going on. This may be a limitation of 1.2 though.

Comment: It's obvious you took some time out of your day to investigate this. Thanks a lot.