# Using StructureMap with unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, structuremap

I'm using StructureMap in a web project for DI IOC. It works perfect, but I don't have a clue how to write unit tests with StructureMap.

Should I do this in AssemblyInitialize start Configuration of StructureMap like in global.asax except for datacontext not to use live LinqToSqlDataContext but some memory data like this:

```
 [AssemblyInitialize]
 public static void Start()
 {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
                {
                    x.For<IDataContext>().HttpContextScoped().Use<MemoryDataContext>()
                        .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
                        .Is(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DEVConnection"].ConnectionString);
                    x.For<IDepartamentRepository>().Use<DepartamentDB>();
                    x.For<IDevelopmentProcess>().Use<DevelopmentProcesses>().OnCreation(c => c.User = Current.CurrentUser);
                    x.For<IActivityProcess>().Use<ActivitiesProcess>().OnCreation(c=> c.User = Current.CurrentUser);
                    x.For<IDevDeveloperRepository>().Use<DevDeveloperDB>();
                    x.For<IDevelopmentRepository>().Use<DevelopmentDB>();
                    x.For<IActivityRepository>().Use<ActivityDB>();
                    x.For<IActivityTypeRepository>().Use<ActivityTypeDB>();
                    x.For<IDevUserRepository>().Use<DevUsersDB>();
                    x.For<IAttachmentRepository>().Use<AttachmentDB>();
                }
            );
 }
```

and then use ObjectFactory.GetInstance() testing or how do I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You shouldn't need to [use a DI Container in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465849/using-ioc-for-unittesting/1465896#1465896) at all.

A container is something you use to wire components together, but a unit test is a test of each component in isolation.

Comment: I agree with that, but what If I have one class that consumes multiple instances, all I would swap using DI is let say DAL to use in memory repository. If my constructor takes 10 interfaces then I need to provide 10 instances manually while using DI, all done automatically. Even if I would create a composition of 10 interfaces into one, I still need to mock it somehow...

Comment: @PawelCioch If your constructor takes ten dependencies, it's [probably doing too much](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2420245/126014). Not only is this a design smell, it's also likely that it will be difficult to test, or at least to maintain the tests.

Comment: I guess I gotta change the job to work with simpler projects :). The class that takes all those is final Service for console app that needs all kinds of repositories and filters. Probably could re-factor but the algorithms are so interconnected that is hard to isolate unit of work. Anyhow thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Mark. Testability is one of the primary reasons you are likely using a container in the first place.

There are times where creating an integration test for your container setup might be a good idea. For example if you have any behavior in your container configuration you will want to create tests for that behavior. In you container config you set **IDataContext**'s connection string via the configuration manager.

The following code is similar to what I do to test such a setup. Notice I avoid ObjectFactory (static singleton objects have their own problems) and wrap my container setup in a bootstrapper helper class:

```
[Test]
public void connection_string_should_come_from_application_configuration()
{
  var container = new ContainerBootstraper().Container;

  var connectionString = container.GetInstance<IDataContext>().ConnectionString

  connectionString.ShouldEqual("test project application configuration connection string");
}
```

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to point the `ShouldEqual` comparison directly to the AppSettings value in question in this case? I won't pretend to have a clue when it comes to unit testing best practices, but as I was reading this I kept thinking it didn't seem to be confirming that it came from configuration.

Comment: Sorry, my example was very terse. I was assuming that the test setup would have given the context necessary. The setup would be responsible for making sure that application setting was present.

Comment: Any chance you can post a sample of what you're doing with that Bootstrapper class?  I'm struggling through some of the same challenges, and I'm not quite bright enough to piece this together.

Comment: @BobbyB Here is an example I have in a public repo: https://github.com/DovetailSoftware/dovetail-bootstrap/blob/master/source/Dovetail.SDK.ModelMap.Integration/Session/bootstrap_ioc.cs