# How to avoid Dependency Injection constructor madness?

Tags: c#, java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I find that my constructors are starting to look like this:

```
public MyClass(Container con, SomeClass1 obj1, SomeClass2, obj2.... )
```

with ever increasing parameter list. Since "Container" is my dependency injection container, why can't I just do this:

```
public MyClass(Container con)
```

for every class? What are the downsides? If I do this, it feels like I'm using a glorified static. Please share your thoughts on IoC and Dependency Injection madness.

Comment: why are you passing the container? I think you may misunderstand IOC

Comment: If your constructors are demanding more or more parameters you may be doing too much in those classes.

Comment: That's not how you do constructor injection.  Objects don't know about the IoC container at all, nor should they.

Comment: You can just create an empty constructor, in which you call the DI directly asking for the stuff you need. That will remove the constructor madnes but you need to make sure you are using a DI Interface.. in case you change your DI system halfway down development. Honestly.. nobody will back doing it this way, even though this is what DI does to inject into your constructor. doh

Answer (score 482, accepted):

You are right that if you use the container as a Service Locator, it's more or less a glorified static factory. For lots of reasons [I consider this an anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) (also see [this excerpt](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/) from my book).

One of the wonderful benefits of Constructor Injection is that it makes violations of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) glaringly obvious.

When that happens, it's time to [refactor to Facade Services](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringToAggregateServices.aspx). In short, create a new, more **coarse-grained** interface that hides the interaction between some or all of the fine-grained dependencies you currently require.

Comment: +1 for quantifying the refactoring effort into a single concept; awesome :)

Comment: for real? you just created an indirection to move those parameters into another class, but they are still there! just more complicated to deal with them.

Comment: @irreputable: In the degenerate case where we move *all* dependencies into an Aggregate Service I agree that it's just another level of indirection that carries no benefit, so my choice of words were slightly off. However, the point is that we move only *some* of the fine-grained dependencies into an Aggregate Service. This limits the number of dependency permutations both in the new Aggregate Service and for the dependencies left behind. This makes both simpler to deal with.

Comment: The best remark: "One of the wonderful benefits of Constructor Injection is that it makes violations of the Single Responsibility Principle glaringly obvious."

Comment: Would it be correct to say that another benefit of constructor injection is it technically forces you to solve any cyclic dependency? (otherwise you get a an infinite recursion creating objects) Because cyclic dependencies is code smell, it's something you should never have. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @DonBox Not necessarily. Tree structures are typically defined with recursion. As long as you have a way to express leaf nodes as empty objects, you can still have recursion.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Here's an example of what I mean: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348221/circular-depedency-how-to-fix-it Is this a good example?

Comment: @DonBox In that case you can write null object implementations to stop the recursion. Not what you need, but the point is that Constructor Injection doesn't prevent cycles - it only makes it clear that they're there.

Answer (score 71):

I don't think your class constructors should have a reference to your IOC container period. This represents an unnecessary dependency between your class and the container (the type of dependency IOC is trying to avoid!).

Comment: +1 Depending on a IoC container makes it hard to change that container later on w/o changing bunch of code in all other classes

Comment: How would you implement IOC without having interface parameters on the constructors?   Am I reading your post wrong?

Comment: @J Hunt I do not understand your comment. To me, interface parameters mean parameters that are interfaces for the dependencies, ie, if your dependency injection container initializes `MyClass myClass = new MyClass(IDependency1 interface1, IDependency2 interface2)` (interface parameters). This is unrelated to @derivation's post, which I interpret as saying a dependency injection container should not inject itself into its objects, ie, `MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this)`

Comment: I don't see how in some cases you can avoid passing the IoC container. Example (probably the only valid one): a factory.

```cs
class MyTypeFactory
{
  private readonly IServiceProvier mServices;

  public MyTypeFactory(IServiceProvier services) => mServices = services;

  MyType Create(int param) => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyType>(mServices, param);
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Mike - `ActivatorUtilities` is how you can avoid passing the container. see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72465953/how-can-i-construct-an-object-outside-of-dependency-injection/72482813#72482813

Comment: That is in my example. And to use `ActivatorUtilities`, one needs to pass on the container.

Answer (score 34):

The difficulty of passing in the parameters is not the problem.  The problem is that your class is doing too much, and should be broken down more.

Dependency Injection can act as an early warning for classes getting too big, specifically because of the increasing pain of passing in all of the dependencies.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but at some point you have to 'glue everything together', and thus you have to get more than a few dependencies for that. For example in the View layer, when building templates and data for them, you have to grab all the data from various dependencies (e.g. 'services') and then put all this data into template and to the screen. If my web page has 10 different 'blocks' of information, so I need 10 different classes to provide me with that data. So I need 10 dependencies into my View/Template class?

Comment: Andrew at that point your webpage might be doing too much. You might want to reconsider the design of your webpage and whether or not it should be split into multiple pages or alternatively various components which are injected separately.  For one thing the webpage's performance is likely terrible.

Answer (score 5):

*Problem :*

1) Constructor with ever increasing parameter list.

2) If class is inherited (Ex: `RepositoryBase`) then changing constructor 
signature causes change in the derived classes.

*Solution 1*

Pass `IoC Container` to constructor

*Why*

- No more ever increasing parameter list
- Constructor's signature becomes simple

*Why not*

- Makes you class tightly coupled to IoC container. *(That causes problems when  1. you want to use that class in other projects where you use different IoC container. 2. you decide to change IoC container)*
- Makes you class less descriptive. *(You can't really look at class constructor and say what it needs for functioning.)*
- Class can access potentially all service.

*Solution 2*

Create a class which groups all service and pass it to constructor

```
 public abstract class EFRepositoryBase 
 {
    public class Dependency
    {
        public DbContext DbContext { get; }
        public IAuditFactory AuditFactory { get; }

         public Dependency(
            DbContext dbContext,
            IAuditFactory auditFactory)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
            AuditFactory = auditFactory;
        }
    }

    protected readonly DbContext DbContext;        
    protected readonly IJobariaAuditFactory auditFactory;

    protected EFRepositoryBase(Dependency dependency)
    {
        DbContext = dependency.DbContext;
        auditFactory= dependency.JobariaAuditFactory;
    }
  }
```

Derived class

```
  public class ApplicationEfRepository : EFRepositoryBase      
  {
     public new class Dependency : EFRepositoryBase.Dependency
     {
         public IConcreteDependency ConcreteDependency { get; }

         public Dependency(
            DbContext dbContext,
            IAuditFactory auditFactory,
            IConcreteDependency concreteDependency)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
            AuditFactory = auditFactory;
            ConcreteDependency = concreteDependency;
        }
     }

      IConcreteDependency _concreteDependency;

      public ApplicationEfRepository(
          Dependency dependency)
          : base(dependency)
      { 
        _concreteDependency = dependency.ConcreteDependency;
      }
   }
```

*Why*

- Adding new dependency to class does not affect derived classes
- Class is agnostic of IoC Container
- Class is descriptive (in aspect of its dependencies). By convention, if you want to know what class `A` Depends on, that information is accumulated in `A.Dependency`
- Constructor signature becomes simple

*Why not*

- need to create additional class
- service registration becomes complex *(You need to register every `X.Dependency` separately)*
- Conceptually same as passing `IoC Container`
- ..

*Solution 2 is just a raw though, if there is solid argument against it, then descriptive comment would be appreciated*

Comment: The resolver will dependency inject the datacontext and interfaces in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I came across a similar question about constructor based dependency Injection and how complex it was getting to pass in all the dependencies.

One of the approach, I have used in past is to use the application facade pattern using a service layer. This would have a coarse API. If this service depends on repositories, It would use a setter injection of the private properties. This requires creating an abstract factory and moving the logic of creating the repositories into a factory.

Detailed code with explanation can be found here

[Best practices for IoC in complex service layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524303/best-practices-for-ioc-in-complex-service-layer/33218635#33218635)

Answer (score 4):

I read this whole thread, twice, and I think people are responding by what they know, not by what is asked.

JP's original question looks like he's constructing objects by sending a resolver, and then a bunch of classes, but we're assuming that those classes/objects are themselves services, ripe for injection. What if they are not?

JP, if you're looking to leverage DI *and* desire the glory of mixing injection with contextual data, none of these patterns (or supposed "anti-patterns") specifically address that. It actually boils down to using a package which will support you in such an endeavor.

```
Container.GetSevice<MyClass>(someObject1, someObject2)
```

... this format is rarely supported. I believe the difficulty of programming such support, added to the miserable performance that would be associated with the implementation, makes it unattractive for opensource developers.

But it should be done, because I should be able to create and register a factory for MyClass'es, and that factory should be able to receive data/input that aren't pushed into being a "service" just for the sake of passing data. If "anti-pattern" is about negative consequences, then forcing the existence of artificial service types for passing data/models is certainly negative (on par with your feeling about wrapping up your classes into a container. Same instinct applies).

There are framework that may help, though, even if they look a bit ugly. For example, Ninject:

[Creating an instance using Ninject with additional parameters in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227548/creating-an-instance-using-ninject-with-additional-parameters-in-the-constructor/2228905)

That's for .NET, is popular, and is still nowhere as clean as it should be, but I'm sure there's something in whatever language you choose to employ.

Answer (score 3):

This is the approach I use

```
public class Hero
{

    [Inject]
    private IInventory Inventory { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private IArmour Armour { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    protected IWeapon Weapon { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private IAction Jump { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private IInstanceProvider InstanceProvider { get; set; }


}
```

Here is a crude approach how to perform the injections and run constructor after injecting values. This is fully functional program.

```
public class InjectAttribute : Attribute
{

}


public class TestClass
{
    [Inject]
    private SomeDependency sd { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ctor");
        Console.WriteLine(sd);
    }
}

public class SomeDependency
{

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object tc = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(TestClass));

        // Get all properties with inject tag
        List<PropertyInfo> pi = typeof(TestClass)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(info => info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectAttribute), false).Length > 0).ToList();

        // We now happen to know there's only one dependency so we take a shortcut just for the sake of this example and just set value to it without inspecting it
        pi[0].SetValue(tc, new SomeDependency(), null);


        // Find the right constructor and Invoke it. 
        ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(TestClass).GetConstructors()[0];
        ci.Invoke(tc, null);

    }
}
```

I am currently working on a hobby project which works like this
https://github.com/Jokine/ToolProject/tree/Core

Answer (score 3):

Injecting the container is a shortcut that you will ultimately regret.

Over injection is not the problem, it is usually a symptom of other structural flaws, most notably separation of concerns. 
This is not one problem but can have many sources and what makes this so difficult to fix is that you are going to have to deal with all of them, sometimes at the same time (think of untangling spaghetti).

Here is an incomplete list of the things to look out for

Poor Domain Design (Aggregate root’s …. etc)

Poor separation of concerns (Service composition, Commands, queries) See CQRS and Event Sourcing.

OR Mappers (be careful, these things can lead you into trouble)

View Models and other DTO’s (Never reuse one, and try to keep them to a minimal !!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Too many parameters for a method is a hint (not necessarily) that your method is too big / has too many responsibilites.

Furthermore, parameters that are used in the same method (may) have a high cohesion -> it is worth considering putting them into one class -> only one parameter must be passed.

Answer (score -7):

What dependency injection framework are you using?  Have you tried using setter based injection instead?

The benefit for constructor based injection is that it looks natural for Java programmers who don't use DI frameworks.  You need 5 things to initialize a class then you have 5 arguments for your constructor.  The downside is what you have noticed, it gets unwieldy when you have lots of dependencies.

With Spring you could pass the required values with setters instead and you could use @required annotations to enforce that they are injected.  The downside is that you need to move the initialization code from the constructor to another method and have Spring call that after all the dependencies are injected by marking it with @PostConstruct.  I'm not sure about other frameworks but I assume they do something similar.

Both ways work, its a matter of preference.

Comment: The reason for constructor injection is to make dependencies obvious, not because it looks more natural for java developers.

Comment: Late comment, but this answer made me laugh :)

Comment: +1 for setter based injections. If I have services and repositories defined in my class its pretty damn obvious they are dependencies.. I don't need to write massive VB6 looking constructors, and do stupid assigning code in the constructor. Its pretty obvious what the dependencies are on the fields required.

Comment: As per 2018, Spring officially recommends not using setter injection except for dependencies that have a reasonable default value. As in, if the dependency is mandatory to the class, constructor injection is recommended. See [discussion on setter vs ctor DI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51670384/5569922)