# Unity automatic injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have already done the following:

1. Register an instance of my Logger
   in unity via a ILogger interface.
2. Created an interface,
   ILoggableObject, that has a method,
   Hook(ILogger logger), to inject my logger.

I would like to accomplish this:

Everytime I ask for any resolution from unity, if that object implements ILoggableObject, automatically inject the ILogger interface via the Hook method.

I think this is possible via interception or policies?

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Why don't you use the constructor injection, which is the default mechanism? Simply rename the `Hook` method to a public constructor (with the same arguments).

Comment: Why not just pass ILogger into whatever objects ctor that needs to use the logging behavior?

Comment: That is how I was doing it.  The problem with that approach is when your objects start using multiple interfaces, you end up with a constructor that has 10 parameters.  Then, another developer who wants to inherit from that base class has to supply all of the constructor parameters that he / she has no need to see.

Comment: You can use Named parameter for calling constructor to avoid this.

Comment: @Saeed, I'm not really clear on how a named parameter would avoid adding a parameter to my constructor.

Comment: @poindexter12: You should never have a constructor that accepts 10 parameters, 5-6 at most. If you do, then theres clearly something wrong with it. And a class like that should be refactored into smaller parts.

Comment: @Robin, this is EXACTLY what I am trying to do.  I have a ILogger that I want all of my classes to have access to.  The logging functionality is isolated in a logging class.  Unfortunately, I have some other utilities (dialogs, errors, etc) which are also isolated in other classes.  I don't want to pass them in the constructor, I just wanted them inject for free into a base class so nobody else has to be concerned about them, they just use it and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is TypeInterception in Unity. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660861(PandP.20).aspx

Also here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660848(v=PandP.20).aspx

You want to intercept the call to the constructor and inject the Logger on behalf of the calling code without them being any wiser.

While I haven't done it before I believe you can do what you want using Intercept.NewInstance()  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff662093(PandP.20).aspx

Answer (score 1):

That is a horrible way to (attempt to) do Dependency Injection. Use **Constructor Injection** instead and inject (via the constructor) the ILogger into the consumer that right now has the Hook method.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.  While I appreciate the feedback, I am converting away from that method because of my comment above.

Comment: However, that reason is a fallacy: too many constructor arguments aren't an indication that Constructor Injection is at fault, but rather that your class has too many responsibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420193/dependency-injection-constructor-madness/2420245#2420245

Comment: Okay, I read your blog post.  It's great.  I agree with all of your principles.  I don't think you are attempting to answer my question though.  While you like constructor injection, others may like property or method injection.  The principal is the same.  I agree that it would be nice for me to aggregate all of my ancillary services into one aggregate service.  I will look into doing this immediately.  My question still stands.  If I have one aggregate service that I would like injected automatically via a method or property, how can I do this automatically?

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't more constructive, but it looks like you got the answer you were looking for. For the record, though, I don't agree that the choice between Constructor, Property or Method Injection is a matter of taste. They are each appropriate in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

While I really like Unity and IoC/DI, I'm not sure that it is the right tool to accomplish what you want to do.

You might consider looking at aspect-oriented programming using [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) or a similar tool. This would allow you to add logging or other cross-cutting concerns without changing the classes being instrumented.