# FactoryBean with @Value in constructor?

Tags: java, spring

Is is possible to add a non-empty default constructor to a `FactoryBean`, where the parameter is injected by `@Value`?

```
@Service
public class DateTimeFormatterFactory implements FactoryBean<DateTimeFormatter> {
    private DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    @Autowired
    public DateTimeFormatterFactory(@Value("${custom.format}") String format) {
        formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    }

    @Override
    public DateTimeFormatter getObject() {
        return formatter;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return DateTimeFormatter.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

/edit: I should have added the error message. Spring complains that there is not "default" constructor without arguments. But if I add one, then my @Value constructor is never called...

Comment: Yes, and the @Autowired is not necessary in your case

Comment: yes :) it is... but are you aware there is a property for that **spring.mvc.date-format** (assume you use spring-boot)

Comment: As far as I know, it should work just like that. Where is the problem here?

Comment: please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
but you don't need a constructor parameter for this.

Instead,
you can create a `PostConstruct` method
and initialize the formatter therein.

For example,

```
@Value("${custom.format}")
private String desiredDateFormat;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct()
{
    formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(desiredDateFormat);
}
```

**Option 2** (A.K.A response to comment)

If you only need the `value` to create the `DateTimeFormatter`,
then just use it to create the `DateTimeFormatter` in a
"setter-like" method that I will call a "settee"
(because I don't know what to actually call it).
Here is some code:

```
@Value("${custom.format}")
public void createDateTimeFormatter(
    final String desiredDateFormat)
{
    formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(desiredDateFormat);
}
```

Comment: The drawback is that I'd have to introduce an extra variable for the `@Value` injection that is afterwards never used again. I tend to avoid variables that are only used once...

Comment: Option 2 is derived from the @Bartosz Bilicki answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562731/spring-autowire-property-vs-setter

Comment: Having the `@Value` on top of the setter (instead on the parameter) worked. That's what I was looking for!