# OOP views getting models without having a long list of classes

Tags: oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am looking for some guidance regarding OOP:

Say for instance i have the following two classes:

```
    public class CallbackModel : SharedModel
{
    public CallbackModel() : base()
    {

    }

    public IList<Callback> getData(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {

        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("SELECT   LAST_UPD AS PERIOD, ");
        query.Append("COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='Færdig' THEN 1 END) as completed, ");
        query.Append("COUNT(CASE WHEN SOLVED_SECONDS /60 /60 <= 2 THEN 1 END) as completed_within_2hours ");
        query.Append("FROM     KS_DRIFT.NYK_SIEBEL_CALLBACK_AGENT_H_V ");
        query.Append("WHERE    LAST_UPD BETWEEN '" + start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' ");
        query.Append("AND      STATUS ='Færdig' ");
        query.Append("GROUP BY LAST_UPD ORDER BY LAST_UPD ASC");
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        var result = session.CreateSQLQuery(query.ToString())
        .AddEntity(typeof(Callback))
        .List<Callback>();

        return result;
    }
}
```

And

```
    public class HenvendelserModel : SharedModel
{

    public HenvendelserModel() : base()
    {
    }

    public IList<Henvendelse> getData(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var query = "SELECT " +
                    "TIDSPUNKT AS PERIOD, " +
                    "NVL(QUEUE,' ') AS QUEUE, " +
                    "NVL(SUM(ANTAL_KALD),0) AS CALLS, " +
                    "NVL(SUM(ANTAL_BESVARET),0) AS ANSWERED_CALLS, " +
                    "CASE WHEN NVL(SUM(BESVARET_25_SEK),0) > 0 THEN ROUND(NVL(SUM(BESVARET_25_SEK),0) / NVL(SUM(ANTAL_KALD),0) * 100) ELSE 0 END AS ANSWER_PERCENT_25, " +
                    "NVL(SUM(INTERN_KALD),0) AS INTERNAL_CALLS " +
                    "FROM     KS_DRIFT.PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT " +
                    "WHERE    TIDSPUNKT >= '"+start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' " +
                    "AND      TIDSPUNKT <= '" + end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' "+
                    "GROUP BY QUEUE, TIDSPUNKT " +
                    "ORDER BY PERIOD";
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        var result = session.CreateSQLQuery(query)
        .AddEntity(typeof(Henvendelse))
        .List<Henvendelse>();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now in my program i have several of these type of classes (for the purpose of example lets say about 7 or 8).

Now my view would have to get an instance of each of these Model classes in order to call the method `getData()`

My question is what is the best way to do this? is it just instantiate each model in the view directly or is it better to use a subclass and have the view ask for each of the models?

i just don't like having a long list of `Model` classes in my view. is there a design pattern for this that i am missing?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2420193/126014