# Passing class instances over a static "container class"

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Is it a good practice to pass instances of classes which are created **only once** at application start to other classes over a static container class which only has getter and setter to get the instance or would that be a use case for singletons?

In my case the class is a representation of the currently logged in user.

Something  like this for example:

```
class ClassA
{}

class ClassB
{
    public void UseClassA()
    {
        ClassA classA = Container.ClassA;
    }
}

class ApplicationStart
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Container.ClassA = new ClassA();
    }
}

static class Container
{
    private static ClassA classA;
    public static ClassA ClassA
    {
        get { return classA; }
        set { classA = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you are trying to implement singleton pattern

Comment: If you have classes which must have only instance then you should use Singleton pattern

Comment: I recommend you to use IoC frameworks for managing your objects lifetime. Whilst it is a bit comples at start to understand how it works - it is very poverful feature which free your code from static cycle dependencies.

Comment: Just a note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: Static members are almost always a bad practice. If we talk about currently authenticated user, then it depends on what application we are talking about. I would say that "currently authenticated user" can be a static member / singleton member for WinForms or WPF environments, but it should be read-only (it should be set by an authentication mechanism, not manually).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good practice to pass instances of classes which are created only once at application start to other classes

Yes! That's called **dependency injection (DI)**, because you inject each object's dependencies as constructor parameters. The application entry point is called the "*[composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)*" in DI parlance:

> A Composition Root is a (preferably) unique location in an application where modules are composed together.

Passing objects to other objects via the constructor is called the Constructor Injection Pattern.

> over a static container class which only has getter and setter to get the instance or would that be a use case for singletons?

Using singletons is almost certainly worse.

[Here's Mark's commentary on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420193/how-to-avoid-dependency-injection-constructor-madness/2420245#2420245):

> You are right that if you use the container as a Service Locator, it's
>   more or less a glorified static factory. For lots of reasons I
>   consider this an anti-pattern.
>
> One of the wonderful benefits of Constructor Injection is that it
>   makes violations of the Single Responsibility Principle glaringly
>   obvious.
>
> When that happens, it's time to refactor to Facade Services. In short,
>   create a new, more coarse-grained interface that hides the interaction
>   between some or all of the fine-grained dependencies you currently
>   require.

Creating a "real" singleton class is [almost certainly worse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons?noredirect=1&lq=1) than instantiating your object, and handing it to the other objects that need it as a constructor parameter.

In your case, I would do something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    // This is your composition root
    var numberProvider = new NumberProvider();
    var b = new B(numberProvider);
    b.DoSomething();
}

class NumberProvider
{
    private int _number = 0;

    // In the real world, maybe this gets a value from a web service
    // and implements an INumberProvider interface so you can mock it
    // for unit testing
    public int GetNumber() => _number++;
}

class B
{
    private readonly NumberProvider _numberProvider;

    public B(NumberProvider numberProvider)
    {
        _numberProvider = numberProvider;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_numberProvider.GetNumber());
    }
}
```

Avoid the public setters. And chances are, you don't need everything to be public.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're asking if it's better to have separate singletons, like this:

```
public class Singleton1
{
    public static Singleton1 Instance { get; set; }
}

public class Singleton2
{
    public static Singleton2 Instance { get; set; }
}
```

Or a single `Container` that takes all them in one place:

```
public static class Container
{
    public static Singleton1 FirstSingleton { get; set; }
    public static Singleton2 SecondSingleton { get; set; }
}
```

Since they are tecnically the same, this is an opinion-based dilemma. It depends about how do you feel about one or the other.

A more interesting question could be: should I either use a static `Container`, or a more advanced (but more complicated) tecnique like *Dependency Injection* with a *Dependency Container*?
But again, it depends on your needs. If you need just a couple of simple Singletons, a simple static `Container` is just fine (remember the golden KISS principle: Keep It Simple, Stupid!). Unless you're using it to store special objects, like an *authenticated user*: in that case, it should be managed by the Authentication classes and policies, as @Yeldar pointed out.