# What are hidden dependencies?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dependencies

Could someone please give me an example of a hidden dependency. I've googled it, and found results like this:

> "A visible dependency is a dependency that developers can see from a
>   class's interface. If a dependency cannot be seen from the class's
>   interface, it is a hidden dependency."

<sub>(Source - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html#visiblehidden)</sub>

But I still don't quite get it.

Does it mean when a dependency is happening inside a function, and not a declared variable in the beginning of a class? Or is it when you simply create functions other than the signature methods declared in an interface?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following is the example of a hidden dependency:

```
class Foo 
{
    void doSomething() //a visible method signature
    {
        //the body of this method is an implementation detail
        //and is thus hidden
        new Bar().doSomething();
    }
}
```

In the above example, `Bar` is a *dependency* for `Foo` because `Foo` relies on the collaboration of `Bar`.

It is *hidden* because the dependency on `Bar` is not explicit in the constructor of `Foo` or method signatures for `Foo`.

Think of a class as defining a *visible contract* exposed to collaborators. The methods and constructor signatures are part of that contract. The body of the method `doSomething()` is *hidden* because it is an internal implementation detail of the class that is not exposed in the contract. All that we know from the signature is that there is a method called `doSomething()` that is of return type `void`.

For a counterexample, we could refactor the class to make the dependencies manifest:

```
class Foo 
{
    private readonly Bar bar;

    Foo(Bar bar) //the constructor signature is visible
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    void doSomething() 
    {
        bar.doSomething(); 
    }
}
```

In the above example, `Bar` is explicitly defined as a dependency in the exposed signature for the constructor.

Alternatively we could do:

```
class Foo 
{

    void doSomething(Bar bar) //method signature is visible
    {
        bar.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Now the dependency on `Bar` for the method `doSomething` is visible as it is included in the method signature for `doSomething`.

Comment: Could the last example be considered Dependency Injection as well?

Answer (score 3):

**Transparent (Concrete) Dependency**: *A Transparent Dependency is a dependency which is set through a public constructor.*

**Opaque (Hidden) Dependency**: *An Opaque Dependency is a dependency that is NOT set through a public constructor, as a result it is not easy to see the dependency*

Here is an example:

```
// Transparent Dependency
public class StudentService
{
    private IStudentRepository _studentRepository;
    public StudentService(IStudentRepository studentRepository)
    {
        _studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return _studentRepository.GetAllStudents();
    }
}

// Opaque Dependency
public class StudentService
{
    public List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        var _studentRepository = new StudentRepository("my-db-name");
        return _studentRepository.GetAllStudents();
    }
}
```

Opaque Dependecies are considered to be an anti-pattern, [this article](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2008/06/08/design-for-testability-transparent-and-opaque-dependencies-part-8/) highlights the problems with Opaque IoC:

1. Writing tests for component implementing Opaque IoC is much harder
2. Transparent IoC helps identity classes which are doing "too much"

[Mark Seemann describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420193/how-to-avoid-dependency-injection-constructor-madness/2420245#2420245) the second point elegantly:

> One of the wonderful benefits of Constructor Injection is that it
>   makes violations of the Single Responsibility Principle glaringly
>   obvious.

Closely related to this is [Nikola's 2nd law of IoC](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection/):

> Any class having more than 3 dependencies should be questioned for SRP
>   violation