# How to avoid a large number of Dependency Injections into a Menu ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, viewmodel

I’m using the WPF RibbonMenu which will hold buttons to launch multiple tools. Probably 50 or more. When a tool is selected from the RibbonMenu, it creates a new tab in my AvalonDock layout.

I’m using a ViewModel-First MVVM pattern and the way I have it working at the moment is each tool `ViewModel` (I have only added two so far) is injected into the RibbonMenu `ViewModel` so it can be added to an `ObservableCollection` which is bound to the AvalonDock Manager.

This works great, but it will mean injecting every tool `ViewModel` (50+) into the Ribbon Menu `ViewModel` which doesn't seem right. I assume each injection will use memory regardless of whether it is used or not by the user?

Similar posts like [How to avoid Dependency Injection constructor madness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420193/how-to-avoid-dependency-injection-constructor-madness) have answers that say a large number of injections in the constructor means that the class is doing too much and needs to be broken up.

But how is this achieved in my situation where I have a need a single `ViewModel` for my RibbonMenu?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to decide whether to use IoC in the RibbonMenu `ViewModel` and have lots of injections (50+), or ignore IoC for this ViewModel only and just create new dependent instances within the ViewModel. For example, each button would trigger a method containing:

```
HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
```

Any advice on the best way forward?

Answer (score 0):

I can say I have not personally tried using a `RibbonMenu` but can you inject a list of ViewModels into the constructor? Something like

```
//Initialize ObservableCollection
public ObservableCollection<IRibbonItemViewModel> RibbonItems = new ObservableCollection<IRibbonItemViewModel>();

//Constructor<>
HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel(List<IRibbonItemViewModel> ribbonViewModels)
{
   foreach(var vm in ribbonViewModels)
   {
       RibbonItems.Add(vm);
   }
}
```

Make sure all ViewModels implement interface `IRibbonItemViewModel`
which could be as simple as

```
public interface IRibbonItemViewModel {}
```