# How can I construct an object outside of dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a bunch of services that use dependency injection to inject a collection of objects like this:

`IRepository<Games> gamesRepo`

this allows the services to use this method without supplying the `this IRepository<Games> repo` parameter:

```
GetSingleGame(this IRepository<Games> repo, GameType type) 
        => repo.Query().Single(p => p.GameType == type);
```

They can do it like this:

`var games = GamesRepo.GetSingleGame(GameType.RPG);`

because `IRepository<Games>` is already supplied via dependency injection.

But I have one controller that needs to use the above method without dependency injection. Is there a way to do this?

When I try to use it like I do above (`var games = GamesRepo.GetSingleGame(GameType.RPG);`), I get this error:

> IRepository does not contain a definition for `GetSingleGame`

How can I construct `IRepository<Games> gamesRepo` outside of using dependency injection?

Comment: Check if the controller contains a `using` statement to the namespace where the `GetSingleGame` extension method is defined.

Comment: @ChristianHeld thank you for responding, it does not, would that work if I added that?

Comment: Yes, that's how extensions methods work, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods for details

Comment: @ChristianHeld I understand what you are saying now.  I do have that using statement up at the top.  For some reason I thought you meant it like this: `using (var reader = new StringReader(manyLines))` my apologies.

Comment: There is no connection between DI and your question. At least I can't see it.

Comment: If your question is how to obtain an instance of `IRepository` without injecting it into the controller's constructor, then you need to create it manually using the `new` operator. But it's not clear how you are calling `var games = GamesRepo.GetSingleGame(GameType.RPG);` if you don't have an instance? Who is `GamesRepo` then? And why you can't inject it into this specific controller? What's special about it?

Comment: @Artur oh I see, so I can just put a new keyword.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ActivatorUtilities` to retrieve the instance *from* dependency injection. Like so:

```
GetSingleGame(GameType type) 
    => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<IRepository<Games>>()
        .Query().Single(p => p.GameType == type);
```