# How to mock a Service that has a lot of constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, reflection, moq

I have inherited an asp.net web api project that follows the normal controller-->service-->repository architecture. This project has no unit tests, and I'm trying to retrofit them.

A typical service in this project goes like this:

```
public class TeamService : ITeamService
{
    private readonly ITeamRepository _teamRepository;
    private readonly ILogger<ITeamService> _logger;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly IPlayerRepository _playerRepository;

    public TeamService(ITeamRepository teamRepository, ILogger<ITeamService> logger,IMapper mapper, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IUserRepository userRepository, IPlayerRepository playerRepository)
    {
        _teamRepository = teamRepository;
        _logger = logger;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _playerRepository = playerRepository;
    }

    //the rest of the service....
}
```

Here we have half a dozen repositories that have to be passed into this service. Nowhere in the project does any code ever create a `TeamRepository` or a `TeamService`. Instead, the `TeamController` looks like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
public class TeamController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ITeamService _teamService;
    private readonly ISchoolService _schoolService;
    public TeamController(ITeamService teamService, ISchoolService schoolService)
    {
        _teamService = teamService;
        _schoolService = schoolService;
    }

    //the rest of the controller....
}
```

and WebApi automagically creates this class and passes the needed `TeamService` into the constructor.

In the web app setup, we have

```
builder.Services.RegisterRepository(Assembly.Load("MyNamespace.Repository"));
builder.Services.RegisterServices(Assembly.Load("MyNamespace.Service")
```

and I guess WebApi does some reflection to load these assemblies, look up the types of all services and repositories, and when someone hits an api endpoint, WebApi creates the needed objects (services, repositories, and controller) by matching the constructor parameters to the known types that implement those interfaces and creating the controller with them.

---

My question is **how do you do a similar thing with Moq**? I want to write a unit test for the `TeamService` and it seems incredibly tedious to have to manually create all the mock repositories (each of which themselves have needed parameters). I'm hoping there's an analogous way to say

- load all the types in `MyNamespace.Mock.Services` and `MyNamespace.Mock.Repositories`
- whenever some constructor parameter needs a type, use the one from those assemblies
- (pseudocode) `var service = Mock.CreateByReflection<TeamService>()`
- `service.TestSomeMethod()`

What is the Moq way of mocking the convenient automagical object creation that WebApi does?

Answer (score 0):

> I have inherited an asp.net web api project that follows the normal controller-->service-->repository architecture

Yes, that is unfortunately quite common, but may cause you problems. It's not your fault, since you've inherited the code base, and I'm only pointing it out because it may cause friction with maintenance, including adding automated tests. At an architectural level, the problem with that kind of implementation is that it [violates the Dependency Inversion Principle](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/03/layers-onions-ports-adapters-its-all-the-same).

This may sound abstract, but has real implications. A common issue that arises is connected to tests, where the test writer repeatedly runs into problems with 'how to mock' something, because abstractions depend on implementation details that are difficult to test.

I'm pointing that out because, if you during your work with adding tests to this code base reach a point where you feel that 'testing sucks', the fault is the application architecture, not unit testing.

All that said, the code base exhibits [Dependency Injection constructor madness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2420193/126014). Again, not your fault, but another code smell to avoid going forward.

Tests really shouldn't have to do the following, but in a legacy code scenario, you may want to consider standing up an [auto-mocking container](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container) for test purposes. You may, for example, combine Moq and Castle Windsor for the purpose. While you *can* use the same Dependency Injection Container that the production code uses, you don't have to do that.

The phrase *auto-mocking* is widely enough adapted that a web search can give you many more examples than the above link.

To be clear, the problem and the proposed solution has little to do with Moq, or any other reflection-based [Test Double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) library. It's a concern related to the management and composition of dependencies, which is separate from the problem of defining test doubles.