# How to reset autofac container?

Tags: unit-testing, autofac

In my tests I setup an autofac container, it returns some real implementation and some mocks (DB, external systems).

The problem is that after each test I Dispose the container and create a new one:
    `Autofac.IContainer.Dispose()` and    `Container = builder.Build();`
The already registered instances are still there.

How can I reset the container so it would be 'like new' again?

The reason why I want to do is - I want to replace one mocked instance with another. It's being registered as Singleton.

---- EDIT

Thanks for the answers. I decided to add some more code and describe what actually I'm trying to achieve. But that is actually a topic for another (prabably already answered question - unit testing CQRS).

My app contains static IContainer property:

```
public static IContainer Container { get; private set; }
```

After each test execution I create it again by calling those two methods:

```
public static ContainerBuilder Compose(IEnumerable<DependencyProvider> dependencyProviders)
{
    var collection = dependencyProviders as List<DependencyProvider> ?? dependencyProviders.ToList();
    var included = new HashSet<DependencyProvider>(collection);
    var includedTypes = new HashSet<Type>(collection.Select(x => x.GetType()));
    var currentWorkingSet = new List<DependencyProvider>(collection);

    while (true)
    {
        var candidates = currentWorkingSet.SelectMany(x => x.GetDependencies());
        var typesToBeAdded = candidates.Where(x => !includedTypes.Contains(x)).Distinct().ToList();
        if (typesToBeAdded.Any() == false)
            break;

       currentWorkingSet.Clear();
       foreach (var type in typesToBeAdded)
       {
            includedTypes.Add(type);
            var instance = CreateInstance(type);
            included.Add(instance);
            currentWorkingSet.Add(instance);
       }
    }

return BuildContainer(included);
}
```

and

```
TestDependencyProvider dependencyProvider = new TestDependencyProvider()
var builder = Compose(new[] { dependencyProvider });
Container = builder.Build();
```

The `TestDependencyProvider` is created for each test and contains moqed instances. It registers those mocks and `x.GetDependencies()` uses the original container registrations i.e. `container.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IAggregateBusinessRuleForEvent<,>));`

The type I'm mostly interested in is one of implementations of `IAggregateBusinessRuleForEvent<,>)`.

```
public class RuleA: IAggregateBusinessRuleForEvent<AEvent, Something>
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public RejectCompanyNameRule(IDependency dependency)
    {
         _dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

So even though I create this container again that `RuleA` is still there and all of my test are using same instance with same `_dependency` :/

It's still not entierly clear why code looks how it looks, I'm trying to understand it by adding tests...

------- EDIT 2

Following Jimmy's advice I've implemented a sample using `Update` me

```
public interface IExample<T>
{
    void Hello();
}

public interface IExampleDependecy
{
    void SaySomething();
}

public class Example : IExample<string>
{
    private IExampleDependecy _dependecy;

    public Example(IExampleDependecy dependecy)
    {
        _dependecy = dependecy;
    }

    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        _dependecy.SaySomething();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void T()
{
    // first test
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IExample<>));
    var mockA = new Moq.Mock<IExampleDependecy>();
    mockA.Setup(d => d.SaySomething()).Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("A"));

    builder.RegisterInstance(mockA.Object).SingleInstance();
    var container = builder.Build();

    var sample1 = container.Resolve<IExample<string>>();
    sample1.Hello();



    // new test using same container
    var updater = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IExample<>));
    var mockB = new Moq.Mock<IExampleDependecy>();
    mockB.Setup(d => d.SaySomething()).Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("B"));
    builder.RegisterInstance(mockB.Object).SingleInstance();
    updater.Update(container); // overwrites existing registrations

    var sample2 = container.Resolve<IExample<string>>();
    sample2.Hello();
}
```

and result is:

```
Hello
A
Hello
A
```

Comment: Why are you using a DI container in your tests and not a Mocking framework (ex: Moq)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm doing it right but the scnario here is a CQRS, Event Sourcing MVC app. 
My test scenario is to execute one command and Assert weather is was executed correctly - Moq object was called.

The command is handled by a handler, handler is registered in IoC and it's dependency it's injected by constructor. Problem here is that even after Dispose, handler is not created again but still lives in the container.

Comment: You may have some valid reasons for using DI containers in your unit test but it's not the "correct" way to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305893/what-should-be-the-strategy-of-unit-testing-when-using-ioc

Comment: Yep. You're absolutely right. Those are really integration tests, executing code in many classes using CQRS framework. 
I could easily unit test my `RulaA` class but I just don't see the point :/ All methods in those classes have one-two statements - is there a point to unit test them? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869633/applying-cqrs-is-unit-testing-the-thin-read-layer-necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autofac by default overrides previous registrations with subsequent ones. That means you don't have to do anything special apart from updating container with your new instance:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterInstance(new Sample("A")).SingleInstance();
var container = builder.Build();
var sample = container.Resolve<Sample>();
// do your test

...

// new test using same container
var updater = new ContainerBuilder();
updater.RegisterInstance(new Sample("B")).SingleInstance();
updater.Update(container); // overwrites existing registrations
var sample = container.Resolve<Sample>(); // returns "B"
```

Comment: I wrote a sample and it didn't work :/
I've added the test and result to the question.

Comment: @Karpik: it does work -- in the `// new test ...` part of your code you need to call `.Register` methods on `updater`, **not on** `builder`, exactly like I did in my sample.