# MEF and unit testing with NUnit

Tags: unit-testing, mef, system.componentmodel

A few weeks ago I jumped on the MEF (ComponentModel) bandwagon, and am now using it for a lot of my plugins and also shared libraries.  Overall, it's been great aside from the frequent mistakes on my part, which result in frustrating debugging sessions.

Anyhow, my app has been running great, but my MEF-related code changes have caused my automated builds to fail.  Most of my unit tests were failing simply because the modules I was testing were dependent upon other modules that needed to be loaded by MEF.  I worked around these situations by bypassing MEF and directly instantiating those objects.

In other words, via MEF I would have something like

```
[Import]
public ICandyInterface ci { get; set; }
```

and

```
[Export(typeof(ICandyInterface))]
public class MyCandy : ICandyInterface
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyCandy( [Import("name_param")] string name) {}
    ...
}
```

But in my unit tests, I would just use

```
CandyInterface MyCandy = new CandyInterface( "Godiva");
```

In addition, the CandyInterface requires a connection to a database, which I have worked around by just adding a test database to my unit test folder, and I have NUnit use that for all of the tests.

Ok, so here are my questions regarding this situation:

1. Is this a Bad Way to do things?
2. Would you recommend composing parts in [SetUp]
3. I haven't yet learned how to use mocks in unit testing -- is this a good example of a case where I might want to mock the underlying database connection (somehow) to just return dummy data and not really require a database?
4. If you've encountered something like this before, can you offer your experience and the way you solved your problem?  (or should this go into the community wiki?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you are on the right track. A unit test should test a **unit**, and that's what you do when you directly create instances. If you let MEF compose instances for you, they would tend towards **integration tests**. Not that there's anything wrong with integration tests, but unit tests tend to be more maintainable because you test each unit in isolation.

[You don't need a container to wire up instances in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465849/using-ioc-for-unittesting/1465896#1465896).

I generally recommend against composing Fixtures in SetUp, as it leads to the [General Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Obscure%20Test.html) anti-pattern.

It is best practice to replace dependencies with [Test Doubles](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html). Dynamic mocks is one of the more versatile ways of doing this, so definitely something you should learn.

Comment: That's some great advice, Mark.  Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: I read the articles that you had posted, and they were very informative.  So it sounds like my current test that creates the SQLite-dependent object should instead have another ICandyInterface test stub (or mock object?  I don't yet see the difference) that just returns whatever data I would expect to get from the DB, without actually using a DB.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that creating the DOCs manually is much better than using MEF composition container to satisfy imports, but regarding the note 'compositing fixtures in setup leads to the general fixture anti pattern' - I want to mention that that's not always the case.

If you’re using the static container and satisfy imports via CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports you will have to face the general fixture anti pattern as CompositionInitializer.Initialize cannot be called more than once. However, you can always create CompositionContainer, add catalogs, and call SatisyImportOnce on the container itself. In that case you can use a new CompositionContainer in every test and get away with facing the shared/general fixture anti pattern

Answer (score 0):

I blogged on how to do unit tests (not nunit but works just the same) with MEF.
The trick was to use a MockExportProvider and i created a test base for all my tests to inherit from.

This is my main AutoWire function that works for integration and unit tests:

```
protected void AutoWire(MockExportProvider mocksProvider, params Assembly[] assemblies){

CompositionContainer container = null;

var assCatalogs = new List<AssemblyCatalog>();

foreach(var a in assemblies)
{
    assCatalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(a));
}

if (mocksProvider != null)
{
    var providers = new List<ExportProvider>();

    providers.Add(mocksProvider); //need to use the mocks provider before the assembly ones            

    foreach (var ac in assCatalogs)
    {
        var assemblyProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(ac);                    
        providers.Add(assemblyProvider);
    }

    container = new CompositionContainer(providers.ToArray());

    foreach (var p in providers) //must set the source provider for CatalogExportProvider back to the container (kinda stupid but apparently no way around this)
    {
        if (p is CatalogExportProvider)
        {
            ((CatalogExportProvider)p).SourceProvider = container;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(assCatalogs));
}

container.ComposeParts(this);        
}
```

More info on my post: https://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/unit-testing-wcf-and-mef/