# Is it a test smell to mix in real implementation and mocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a consumer class responsible for consuming a string and deciding what to do with it. It can either parse and insert the parse data in a database or notify an administrator.

Below is my implementation.

```
public void Consume(string email)
{
    if(_emailValidator.IsLocate(email))
    {
        var parsedLocate = _parser.Parse(email);

        // Insert locate in database
    }
    else if(_emailValidator.IsGoodNightCall(email))
    {
        // Notify email notifying them that a locate email requires attention.
        _notifier.Notify();
    }
}
```

Below is my unit test.

```
// Arrange
var validator = new EmailValidator();
var parser = new Mock<IParser>();
var notifier = new Mock<INotifier>();
var consumer = new LocateConsumer(validator, parser.Object, notifier.Object);
var email = EmailLiterals.Locate;

// Act
consumer.Consume(email);

// Assert
parser.Verify(x => x.Parse(email), Times.Once());
```

Is it code smell to mix mocks and real implementation in unit tests? Also, how do always having to test whether method `abc()` always ran once? It doesn't seem right that once I add a new unit test every time I add a function inside my `if` block. Seems like if I continue adding to my `Consume` method I'm create a trap.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be nitpicking, a unit test is an **automated test that tests a unit in isolation**. If you combine two or more units, it's not a unit test any more, it's an **integration test**.

However, depending on the type of units you integrate, having lots of that type of integration tests may be quite okay.

Krzysztof Kozmic recently wrote a blog post about this where he describes how [Castle Windsor has very few unit tests](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2011/02/28/unit-tests-are-overrated.aspx), but lots of integration tests. [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) also has a large share of those types of integration tests. I think the most important point is that as a general rule the **integration must not cross library boundaries**.

In any case you can view the *actual implementation* as an extreme end of the [Test Double Continuum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163358.aspx), so just as there are scenarios where it makes sense to use Stubs, Mocks, Spies, or Fakes, there are also **scenarios where the actual implementation may make sense**.

However, just keep in mind that you are no longer testing the unit **in isolation**, so you do introduce a coupling between the units that **makes it more difficult to vary each independently**.

To conclude, I still consider it a *smell* because it should always be an occasion to stop and think. However, a smell indicates no more than that, and sometimes, once you've thought it over, you can decide to move along.

Comment: +1 mybe we should invent a new term **lightweight integratintest** or **nearly unittest** that combine just a few classes within a library as an acceptable-effort-tradeof-smell :-)

Comment: Yes, that was also my first thought as I read Krzysztof's post, but I've yet to come up with a good, catchy name.

Comment: +1 Great answer. While I agree with everything you said I'm not sure I quite follow when you say. I do agree that my test introduces coupling between modules. Short of using a container to wire up my modules in this test (which I'm not convinced is the best route to use) how do I avoid coupling? It seems rather inevitable. In the application itself it's not a problem because I wire everything up using Windsor and resolve my main object in the composition root (great article by the way). Only solution I can think of is to wire up my `Consumer` class in a set up method via poor man's DI.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, perhaps this answer may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465849/using-ioc-for-unittesting/1465896#1465896

Answer (score 3):

I would say a strong yes. Unit testing should be free of dependencies among components.

Answer (score 3):

```
> Is it a test smell to mix in real implementation and mocks?
```

This is an **integration test** (combining 2 or more modules) and not a unittest (test one module in isolation)

My answer is **No**: I think it is ok to have mocks in integration test.

Comment: +1 However, I think the answer requires a little more elaboration, so I added my own thoughts as a separate answer.