# Dependency injection with unity in a class library project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am new with the dependency injection pattern. I'm a little confused about few things.

### Scenario:

I have a class library project called 'MailCore'. This project has interfaces and classes that perform all email sending stuff.
I have an MVC project called 'The site'. It uses the 'MailCore' project to send email. I have Unity in this project and the UnityContainer is registered and things are working fine.

I also have another class library library project called 'SiteRepo'. Sometimes, to perform some specific tasks, I have to send email from this project. Therefore the 'MailCore' project is referenced in this project, too.

### Problem:

I have installed Unity from NuGet in the 'SiteRepo' project and it doesn't seem to create any UnityConfig in this class library project.
How would I register a UnityContainer here?

### Code:

TheSite:

```
Public class JobController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmailBuilder mailBuilder;
    public JobController(IEmailBuilder mailBuilder)
    {
        this.mailBuilder = mailBuilder;

    }
    public ActionResult Create(....)
    {
      JobRepo j = new JobRepo();
      j.Create(....);
    }

}
```

UnityConfig (this is in the web app 'The Site'):

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

        container.RegisterType<IEmailBuilder, EmailBuilder>();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

SiteRepo:

```
Public class JobRepo()
{
   Public bool Create(...) 
   {
       //some other code to create a job....

       //have to send email using MailCore !! The problem area in concern..
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe this question deserves a better answer other than use something other than Unity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *must* use a DI Container like Unity (instead of [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di)), you should install it into your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), which is 'The site'.

From there, you can [reference the library projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503612/126014) and configure your container.

Comment: I already have unity installed in the 'The Site'. And 'The Site' has 'SiteRepo' and 'MailCore' Referenced individually. But i have some situations where, 'The Site' calls a method from 'SiteRepo'. and inside that method 'SiteRepo' calls a method from 'MailCore' to send email. So based on your answer and all the links you provided, does it mean i should move that email sending code out of 'SiteCore' and bring it to 'The Site' ??

Comment: Since 'The Site' references both libraries, it should be possible to configure Unity to inject a type from MailCore into the class in SiteRepo that hosts the method you care about.

Comment: Mark, SiteRepo has a class called JobRepo which has a method called CreateJob. This CreateJob should call a something in MailCore to send email. JobRepo class does not implement any Interface from MailCore. In this case how would I configure unity ?? Isn't it container.RegisterType<interface, implementing class>() ?? Sorry if I sound like stupid :)

Comment: IIRC, with Unity, you don't have to register concrete classes; Unity will just pick them up and create them for you.

Comment: Correct, you do not need to register concrete classes if you are ok with the defaults: (transient lifetime, no name, no interception, no property injection).  But you can register a concrete type if you want to customize the registration.  `container.RegisterType<MyConcreteType>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());` (to register as a singleton for example)

Comment: @MarkSeemann I am working with Unit Test Project(For Integration testing my service layer without controller), which unlike MVC project do not have DependencyResolver, So where should I put my UnitContainer object so that while loading an object in memory it automatically resolves the registered types.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Compose object graphs in your tests https://stackoverflow.com/a/1465896/126014

Comment: What If I don't want a direct reference from my site to my repository? If this is the only way to register my associations, it seems rather limiting. I think the OP has a valid scenario that should have an answer.