# How do I use MOQ with Xamarin.Forms DependencyService

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, moq

I am writing a `Xamarin.Forms` project which I am now trying to `Unit Test` currently I use the [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) like so:

**PCL Interface**

```
public interface IGetDatabase
{
   string GetDataBase()
}
```

**Device specific Implementation**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyProject.Droid.GetDatabaseImplementation))]
class GetDatabaseImplementation: IGetDatabase
{
   public string GetDatabase()
   {
       return "MyDatabasePath";
   }
}
```

And it is called in the **PCL** like so:

```
DependencyService.Get<IGetDatabase>().GetDatabase();
```

Now I would like to `unit Test` this using `MOQ` to Mock my interface implementation so that my implementations are generated at runtime. I don't want to write a mock class as my actual example is more complicated so means it wont work.

How would I go about doing this? Is my `DepdencyService` too tightly coupled to `Xamarin`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1465896/126014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only register a class that implements an interface in the current application. You need a dependency injection framework that allows you to register

a) an object instance or

b) a method that creates and returns a new mock

as the implementation for an interface.

There are many different dependency injection containers for C# available. I use `Mvx` which comes with MvvmCross. It allows you to register mocks created wit `Moq`.

**Example**

```
var myMoq = new Moq<IGetDatabase>();
Moq.Setup(x => x.GetDatabase()).Returns(() => "MyMockDatabasePath");
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IGetDatabase>(() => myMoq.Object);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought I had to do, just wondered if there was a way to do it with `Xamarin.Forms DependencyService` but it looks like there isn't and I'm going to have to refactor. I'll update this answer with some example code