# Dependency Injection (Unity): Where to RegisterTypes in Unit Test Project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, unity-container

Brand new to Unity and I am trying to figure out where I need to Register Types in a Visual Studio Unit Test Project (it's a project that has a ton of tests, so I am finding that it would be a good place to implement Unity for learning).

I have a base class (BaseTestClass) that all the TestClasses inherit from.  This is the one where it would be lovely to have some dependency injection working, however, I don't know where a valid place would be to create the container and RegisterType(s) so that they can be auto injected.

**Base Class:**

```
public class BaseTestClass
{
    protected IApplicationContext ApplicationContext;

    public BaseTestClass(IApplicationContext appContext)
    {
        ApplicationContext = appContext;
    }
}
```

**Derived class:**

```
[TestClass]
public class RelationTest : BaseTestClass
{
    public RelationTest(IApplicationContext appContext) : base(appContext)
    {
        CreateNodeType();
    }
}
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1465849/126014

Comment: Just don't. It's unit testing.

Comment: I don't see how a base class can be configured with all the dependencies a derived class might need.