# Ninject modules or organising wiring up dependencies

Tags: c#, ioc-container, ninject

I've started playing with Ninject and from a screencast it states the following is how you set up a binding:

```
class MyModule : StandardModule {

    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IInterface>().To<ConcreteType>();
        // More bindings here...
    }
}
```

This is all very good.

However suppose you have one hundred objects used in an application. That would mean this would have one hundred bindings. Is this correct?

Secondly, I presume that given such an application it may be split into subsystems such as GUI, Database, Services and so on.

Would you then create a custom module for each subsystem which in turn would be:

- GUIModule
- DatabaseModule
- ServiceModule
- ...

For each module you'd have the correct bindings that they required. Am I on the right page here?

Finally would this binding all occur in `Main` or the entry point for your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However suppose you have one hundred
>   objects used in an application. That
>   would mean this would have one hundred
>   bindings. Is this correct?

One hundred registered components, yes, but not necessarily registered one by one. There's a [Convention extension for Ninject](http://github.com/idavis/ninject.extensions.conventions) that allows you to scan assemblies and register types based on some defined rules. See [this test](http://github.com/idavis/ninject.extensions.conventions/blob/master/source/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Tests/GenericBindingGeneratorTests.cs) as an example.

> Would you then create a custom module
>   for each subsystem

Again, not necessarily. You might just want to register all your repositories (just to name something) in a single convention registration.

> For each module you'd have the correct
>   bindings that they required.

As with any "module" (be it assembly, class, application) the concepts of [coupling and cohesion](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CouplingAndCohesion)  apply here as well. It's best practice to keep coupling low (don't depend too much on other modules) and cohesion high (all components within a module must serve towards a common goal)

> Finally would this binding all occur
>   in Main or the entry point for your
>   application?

Yes, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475575/where-should-i-do-dependency-injection-with-ninject-2).