# Ninject GetAll Where Module = foo

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

Is it possible to do something like this:

`var foos = Kernel.where(c=>c.module == myModule).GetAll<foo>;`

And how would one go about it?

If(!possible)
How can you discriminate between bindings to the same interface when using the GetAll() method?
I am aware of `WithParameter`, `WithMetadata`, `WithConstructorArgument` and `WithPropertyValue`; Which one should i use and why?

Cheers

---

**More information**

I need this because I am creating a plugin framework. During the routing the plugin framework needs to be able to determine which controller's to look at. If there are multiple home controllers across plugins it wont work as expected.
I need to be able to differentiate which plugin registered which IController implementation so that the controller factory knows to send the request to a controller in a specific plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up attaching metadata to each one:

```
Bind<IController>().To<MyController>()
   .Named(implementation.GetType().Name.Replace("Controller", string.Empty))
   .WithMetadata("Plugin", PluginName);`
```

Then routing my plugins like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Plugin1",
                url: "Plugin1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { Plugin = PluginName, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And in the controller factory GetControllerType method

```
object requestedModule;
if (requestContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("Plugin", out requestedPlugin))
    controller = kernel.GetAll<IController>(c => c.Name == controllerName && c.Get<string>("module", string.Empty) == (string)requestedPlugin).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at using When(), so you don't have to do this?

i.e.

```
Bind<IInterface>().To<YourConcreteTypeOne>().When(r => r.Target.Name == "concreteObjectOne");
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396285/ninject-2-0-binding-to-a-object-that-uses-the-same-interface-more-than-once) in the accepted solution (updated section).  Ideally you shouldn't really need to access the kernel after you've set your bindings otherwise you're tightly coupling yourself to your DI framework.  If this isn't applicable please do expand your question to include more code.

Comment: I've updated the question with more information. I can't really provide a small bit of code without providing the rest. My understanding of `r.target` is that it is the class which has called asked for the instance, if so that wont work because there is one class that calls it all.

Comment: I presume by Module you mean a Ninject module?

Comment: Sorry, i call my plugins modules sometimes, i edited the question so that its easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is that you define an interface i.e. `IControllerProvider` which has a `Name` and a `GetController` method. Your core product loads all scanned IControllerProvider implementations and gets the controllers and registers them with a name and the Icontroller instace in the kernel. With that approach your plugins can use their own containers or simply do poor man DI. Your routing handler can then acquire an `IEnumerable<IController>`. Or better simply put the name onto the `IController` interface, so that you don't need t fallback to ninject metadata.

Comment: I am doing that, however there is a problem with that solution. When you have a few plugins with HomeController's it doesnt have a way to determine which one

Comment: Yeah but that is custom logic which you have to write anyway in your handler class which gets the IControllers injected. There is now way ninject can magically help you