# How to get all instances from the module loaded in a Ninject kernel?

Tags: c#, ninject

Ninject provides convenient way for separating bindings into modules and also the `GetAll<T>()` method of the `IResolutionRoot` to get all instances for the given type.

I have multiple modules registering multiple classes implementing the same type, e.g.:

```
interface IFoo { }
class FooA : IFoo { } // in Module1
class FooB : IFoo { } // in Module2
class FooC : IFoo { } // in Module2
```

Is it possible to retrieve only the instance of the `FooC` by requesting `IFoo` after loading `Module2` in the kernel with the `Module1` already loaded?
Something like:

```
StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new Module1()); // Module1 registered

Module2 module2 = new Module2();
kernel.Load(module2);
// kernel.GetAll<IFoo>().Where( ... from Module2 ... );
```

The only thing I thought of is to get all the registered bindings by `Module2`. But then, how to retrieve instances?

```
var fooBindings = module2.Bindings.Where(b => b.Service.Equals(typeof(IFoo)));

// and then something like:
var instances = fooBindings.Select(b => kernel.Get(b));
// or kernel.Resolve(b) where b is instance of IBinding

// then: instances will contain only FooC, not the FooA and FooB.
```

I know that similar question has been asked here: [Ninject GetAll Where Module = foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503239/ninject-getall-where-module-foo)
But is it not possible to leverage the `Bindings` member exposed by the module for that?