# How to instantiate objects of classes that have dependencies injected?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, constructor-injection

Let's say I have some class with dependency injected:

```
public class SomeBusinessCaller {
   ILogger logger;
   public SomeBusinessCaller(ILogger logger) {
       this.logger = logger;
   }
}
```

My question is, how do I instantiate an object of that class? Let's say I have an implementation for this, called AppLogger. After I say

```
ObjectFactory.For<ILogger>().Use<AppLogger>();
```

how do I call constructor of SomeBusinessCaller? Am I calling

```
SomeBusinessCaller caller = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<SomeBusinessCaller>();
```

or there is a different strategy for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which uses `caller` does not live in a vacuum. Instead of assuming you need to create an instance of `SomeBusinessCaller` yourself, simply declare a dependency on it:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public SomeOtherClass(SomeBusinessCaller caller)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The container will figure out that `SomeBusinessCaller` requires an `ILogger`, and it will automatically provide an instance of `AppLogger`.

And, when something needs an instance of *that* class:

```
public class YetAnotherClass
{
    public YetAnotherClass(SomeOtherClass other)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you follow that logic for all the objects you write, eventually you will have exactly 1 object for which you actually request an instance:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // ...Initialize ObjectFactory...

    var compositionRootObject = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<YetAnotherClass>();

    compositionRootObject.DoYourThing();
}
```

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. So, I need to set up container and then instantiate only one object via GetInstance call? All its dependencies will be satisfied automagically by the container?

Comment: Exactly. If you need to create an object *after* you have resolved the root object, you should register a factory with the container and take that in the constructor of the object which needs to create the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which DI Container you use, then **yes**: ask the container to provide you with an instance of `SomeBusinessCaller`.

The container should use **auto-wiring** to automatically figure out that the SomeBusinessCaller requires an instance of `ILogger`, and since `AppLogger` is registered, it can satisfy that requirement.

However, [don't use the DI Container as a static Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Instead, you should let the DI Container compose your entire dependency graph in one go in the application's [Composition Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475575/where-should-i-do-dependency-injection-with-ninject-2/1475861#1475861).

Comment: I understand that auto-wiring must figure out requirements of the class, but calling side still needs to provide a parameter for the class constructor

Comment: The container supplies the parameter by creating an `AppLogger` instance for you. You shouldn't have to supply it yourself.

Comment: so, parameterless constructor will do the job?

Comment: You should only use default constructors for those classes where it makes sense. If `AppLogger` takes dependencies in its constructor, just register those with the container as well. The container will resolve all dependencies until all are satisfied (or it runs into something that's not registered).