# When to use an IOC container?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm trying to understand when I should use a container versus manually injecting dependencies.  If I have an application that uses a 1-2 interfaces and only has 1-2 concrete implementations for each interface, I would lean towards just handling that myself.

If I have a small application that uses 2-3 interfaces and each interface has 2-3 concrete implementations, should I use a full-blown container?  Would something something simple like [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/20/Building-an-IoC-container-in-15-lines-of-code.aspx) suffice?

Basically I'm trying to understand when it's appropriate to manually handle these dependencies, when (or if) I should use something simple like the above, and when to use an IOC container like Ninject, Windsor, etc....  It might not be appropriate to put a number on something like this, but how can I tell it's time to use an IOC container?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code

Comment: I'm not asking why I should use one, I'm asking when I should use one.  I'm already aware of the benefits, but I'm unsure about when is the correct time to use one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The important thing to realize here is that you can (and should) write your code in a [DI-friendly, but container-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library/2047657#2047657) manner.

This means that you should always push the composition of dependencies to a point where you can't possibly defer it any longer. This is called the [Composition Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475575/where-should-i-do-dependency-injection-with-ninject-2/1475861#1475861) and is often placed in near the application's entry point.

If you design your application in this way, your choice of DI Container (or no DI Container) revolves around a single place in your application, and you can quickly change strategy.

You can choose to use **Poor Man's DI** if you only have a few dependencies, or you can choose to use a full-blown **DI Container**. Used in this fashion, you will have no dependency on any particular DI Container, so the choice becomes **less crucial** in terms of maintainability.

A DI Container helps you manage complextity, including object lifetime. Used like described here, it doesn't do anything you couldn't write in hand, but it does it **better and more succinctly**. As such, my threshold for when to start using a DI Container would be pretty low.

I would start using a DI Container once I get past a few dependencies. [Most of them are pretty easy to get started with anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515124/whats-the-simplest-ioc-container-for-c/2515178#2515178).

---

Update: My [November 2012 answer to that question](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer).