# IS Depenedency Injectin replace by Factory Design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

Dependency Injection internally create and assig the object to dependent object.
Factory pattern : Creation of objects without exposing the instantiation logic to the client.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16122466/126014

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2598659/126014

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/557742/126014