# Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation and TryGetInstance

Tags: .net, ioc-container

Why `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator` does not offer TryGetInstance()?

I need to get generic validator instance `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEntityValidator<TEntity>>()` but not all Entities has registered validator.

The only solution i found is to use try{}catch{} block, but i dont like this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell you why this method doesn't exist, but I would like to offer the opion that it **shouldn't matter** because you shouldn't be using DI Containers in a **pull-based** way in any case. This is [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

If you need an `IEntityValidator<Foo>`, then request the dependency through the constructor:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IEntityValidator<Foo> validator;

    public Foo(IEntityValidator<Foo> validator)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
    }
}
```

You can handle the issue that not all Entities have registered validators in different ways.

My preferred approach would be to register a [Null Validator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) for all those entities.

Alternatively, you can give your Entities a constructor overload that *doesn't* take a validator, and then assign a Null Validator from that constructor. That might look like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IEntityValidator<Foo> validator;

    public Foo()
    {
        this.validator = new NullValidator<Foo>();
    }

    public Foo(IEntityValidator<Foo> validator)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
    }
}
```

However, whether that work or not partially depends on your particular DI Container. As an example, Castle Windsor uses the most greedy constructor *it can satisfy* so in that case it would work well even when validators are not registered, because it would just pick the default constructor.

In any case, the **push-based** approach is **true Dependency Injection**. With that approach, you use the DI Container to [resolve the entire dependency graph in one go at the application's entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475575/where-should-i-do-dependency-injection-with-ninject-2/1475861#1475861).

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this is not supported by the CSL is that not all IoC frameworks support this mechanism. The Common Service Locator discussion forum has a workaround for this issue. [Read this question](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=44293).

I agree with Mark that you should try registering a *Null Object* is you can and stick to true dependency injection when possible.