# What's the best design for this problem with IoC and Circular Reference

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, circular-reference

I'll try to explain in the simple way.

I have a solution (c# 4.0) that contain 4 projects

- Framework
- DAL
- Domain
- WebApplication

So my question is:

Framework is the right place to configure my Unity IoC? I want to configure via code and not with xml, so Framework need to know reference of DAL but DAL already knows Framework.

All my projects will know Framework, so where i configure my IoC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications should be configured in the **Composition Root**, which is as close to the entry point as possible. In your case, that would be the WebApplication. That's the **only project which should have a reference to Unity**. None of the other projects should have any reference to Unity at all.

In the composition root, you should follow the [Register Resolve Release](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx) pattern.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475575/where-should-i-do-dependency-injection-with-ninject-2/1475861#1475861) - it talks about Ninject instead of Unity, but the concept (and hence the answer) is the same.