# What is the correct layer to configure your IoC container when using a service layer?

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container

I have a medium sized asp.net MVC app.  It consumes a service layer that handles all the repository use, calling domain services, etc.  My controller actions are very slim -- they basically call a service class, get a response and show that respose.  Most components are interface based with some poor man's DI.  The app is growing, needs better testing support, and starting to call out for an IoC container.

Everything I read (such as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410719/design-where-should-objects-be-registered-when-using-windsor/1410738#1410738)) states that I should configure the IoC at the application root.  This makes sense to me if I were using repositories right from my controller actions and needed DI at the controller level, but I'm not.  It seems like I'd want my composition root in my service layer.  I keep thinking that I don't want my web.config (or another config) at the UI layer even mentioning/seeing/hearing about a repository, credit card processor, etc.

Am I thinking about this the right way or do I just need to get over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get over it :)

Having your **Composition Root** in the application root doesn't require you to have a lot of DI Container stuff in web.config. You can if you will, but it's optional. What is *not optional* when putting the Composition Root in the application root is that you need to have some DI code in Global.asax.

You may find it irrelevant because your Controllers are so thin, but that's not the real point. The actual point is that you (the abstract 'you') want to postpone coupling classes until the **last responsible moment**. The earlier you couple types, the less flexibility you have.

If you couple classes in the service layer, you make an irreversible decision at that point. If it later turns out that you need to compose those services differently, you can't - not without recompiling, that is.

If there was a major benefit of doing it, I can understand why you would want to, but there isn't. You may as well wait composing all components untill you absolutely must do so - and that's in the application's entry point.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same situation as you and I tackle it as follows.

The general rule I use is what ever has a global.asax or something similar, it needs to execute the code that registers the IoC components. Another way of putting it is that you need to run it one for each different process that is running (i.e. the website is in one process and the service is in another).

In my case I do this once for the mvc website global.asax and again for the server. In this case the registrations that get made would be different between the service and the website.

In addition I do one more thing. Due to the fact that I reuse components between the mvc app and the service (i.e. logging) I have a third core component that registers the core IoC components for the system and this component is called by the both the website and services registrations. Hence I anything that is common between the service and the website go into the core registration and then anything that is different goes into the 'interface' specific registration.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a Java perspective, I use the Spring framework for my IoC container.  With it, the container really is application-wide.  Although you can have different configuration files for different layers (a persistence config file, a services config file, a controller config file, etc), all of objects (beans in Java lingo) go into the container.

I think this still ok though because there is no coupling between classes as you mentioned.  A view does not need to know about a credit card processor, just because they are in the same IoC container.  These classes will receive (by injection) only the dependencies they need, and are not concerned with other objects in the container.