# How should the web.config look like in Unity Dependency Injection for WCF services?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am creating new instnace provider which resolve services through Unity. 
I am not sure how to add the configuration in web.config.
Following is my service class.

public class Service : IService 
{

```
private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork; 

private IMyRepository _myRepository; 

// Dependency Injection enabled constructors 

public Service(IUnitOfWork uow, IMyRepository myRepository) 
{ 
    _unitOfWork = uow; 
    _myRepository = myRepository; 
} 

public bool DoWork()
{
        return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [only use web.config if you need to be able to vary the services after compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512316/ioc-dependency-injection-please-explain-code-versus-xml/2513933#2513933). That should not be regarded as the default scenario.

This means that in most cases it would be better to resort to **Code as Configuration**, like this:

```
container.RegisterType<Service>();
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, MyUnitOfWork>();
container.RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

If you must use XML configuration you can do something similar. [Unity's excellent documentation explains the details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx).

It would probably go something like this:

```
<container>
  <register type="Service" />
  <register type="IUnitOfWork" mapTo="MyUnitOfWork" />
  <register type="IMyRepository" mapTo="MyRepository" />
</container>
```

Comment: No need to register the Service type.

Comment: Right; it's necessary with some other containers, but not Unity :)