# Update constructor injection parameter value

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Using the Unity Framework and constructor injection I have this configuration:

```
<dependencyInjection>
  <type name="IInfoService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IInfoService" type="Services.IInfoService, Services" />

    <alias alias="InternWS" type="Services.InternWS.Info, Services.InternWS" />
    <alias alias="Mock" type="Services.Mock.Info, Services.Mock" />

    <container>
        <register type="IInfoService" mapTo="Mock">
          <constructor>
            <param name="name" value="mockservice" />
          </constructor>
        </register>
        <register type="IInfoService" mapTo="InternWS" name="InternWS_Service">
          <constructor>
            <param name="name" value="InternWS_Service" />
            <param name="endpoint" value="http://staging.webservices/infoservice.svc" />
          </constructor>
        </register>
    </container>
  </type>
</dependencyInjection>
```

It works perfectly.
For my different environments, I have to point to different web services with the configuration like this:

- param name="endpoint" value="http://development.webservices/infoservice.svc"
- param name="endpoint" value="http://test.webservices/infoservice.svc"
- param name="endpoint" value="http://acceptance.webservices/infoservice.svc"
- param name="endpoint" value="http://production.webservices/infoservice.svc"

I would like to change this to:

- param name="endpoint" value="http://[Environment].webservices/infoservice.svc"

and use parameter override to set the real value:

```
var parameterOverrides = new ParameterOverrides();
foreach(var ? in ?)
{
  var paramName = ?;
  var paramValue = ?;
  parameterOverrides.Add(paramName, paramValue.Replace("[Environment]", GetEnvironment()));
}
container.Resolve<T>(item.Name, parameterOverrides);
```

Is this the best way?
How do I find the paramName and paramValue?
This is not to change the values while running, but to have 1 config file for every step in the DTAP street.
In the config file there are like 30 of these sections, which have to be checked.

Comment: Which DI library are you using? Spring, Autofac, Unity, Ninject, StructureMap? Something else?

Comment: Hi Stevan, I use Unity

Comment: Don't use XML configuration like that. "swapping dependencies without recompilation is typically only relevant for a small subset of all your loosely coupled code": https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513933/264697

Comment: That's not the issue. On a deploy to a different environment, I don't want to go to all the configurations values. The value doesn't change while running.