# IOC best practice: How to best manage dependency graph?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap, ioc-container

I am doing an MVC project with structuremap as an IOC container. We are doing TDD, and I want to set up my dependencies so that its easy to work with, and so that its easy to test.

How should I best set up the graph of dependencies for the below fictional illustrated graph ?

- ApplicationController

  - Controller

    - AuthenticationService

      - UserRepository

Do you inject the userrepository on the controller, and further from the in the authenticationservice? And what if the graph is deeper - will you not get a lot of dependencies starting on the controller?

If you have a dependency on you applicationcontroller, do you also inject that on the controller, and that way up on the base?

If I let the container resolve the instance somewhere in the middle of the graph, I would have to setup the container for testing? Is that a good thing to do, or best avoided?

Is there another way, that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dependency graph looks fine. As illustrated, each class only has **one** dependency

- ApplicationController depends on Controller
- Controller depends on AuthenticationService
- AuthenticationService depends on UserRepository

I realize that this is a simplified view, and that your real production architecture will be much more complex, but the nice thing about DI (and **Constructor Injection** in particular) is that it makes violations of the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) so obvious.

Whan a class starts getting too many dependencies, it's a sign that you should [refactor to an Aggregate Service](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringToAggregateServices.aspx).

The final dependency graph may be **huge**, but each class only depends on a few abstractions, so from an architectural point of view, this is not a problem.

You should never have to resolve the instance in the middle of the graph. Resolving is something that you [do in the Composition Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410719/design-where-should-objects-be-registered-when-using-windsor/1410738#1410738), and (theoretically) only once.

When it comes to unit testing, you [shouldn't have to use a DI Container at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465849/using-ioc-for-unittesting/1465896#1465896).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your applicationController relates to your controller but in general, your controller would have a dependency on your service and your service would have a dependency on the repository.

e.g.

```
public MyXyzController
{
  public MyXyzController(IAuthenticationService authenticationService){...}
}

public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
  public AuthenticationService(IUserRepository userRepository){...}
}
```

In this way, your IOC container will automatically resolve all dependencies when you ask for (ie resolve) the controller.

Comment: Do I then setup the container for test?

Comment: No, as Mark Seemann said you should not need the IOC container at all when unit testing. You would just test one component at a time and mock or stub any dependencies. You can use a mocking framework (e.g. Moq) to inject a mock into each component under test and then your can verify that methods on your dependency are called correctly.