# Are the words "IoC container" and "DI container" synonyms, or separate concepts?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, service-locator

I'm currently wading my way through articles and questions on the subject of *IoC containers*, such as:

- [Why do I need an IoC container as opposed to straightforward DI code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code)
- [What's the difference between the Dependency Injection and Service Locator patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557781/whats-the-difference-between-the-dependency-injection-and-service-locator-patte)
- [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) (M.F.)
- [Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) (M.S.)
- [When to use a DI Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) (M.S.)
- [Are we using IoC effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488801/are-we-using-ioc-effectively?noredirect=1&lq=1)

There's something that doesn't strike me as obvious right now.

As far as I understand, *dependency injection (DI)* in its purest form is the following, formulated by myself:

> As an object that depends on some abstract services, I don't have to look for these concrete services; concrete instances of them will be provided to me when an instance of myself is created, or very shortly after.

This puts *DI* directly in contrast with a *service locator*, as I reformulate:

> As an object that depends on some abstract services, I know someone I can call who can provide me with these concrete services; I will ask them for a concrete instance when I require it.

My current understanding of a *DI container* is this:

> As the DI container, I know concrete classes of services that I need to create, and for each class, what abstract services each of them require; I will therefore create instances of these services and provide their dependencies.

I don't find obvious what an *IoC container* is right now due to conflicting understanding. Depending on the article I'm reading, it looks like:

- Either a *IoC container* is a synonym for *DI container* as the two terms are used interchangeably

  - This is what I understand when reading M.F. and M.S. articles
- *DI container* is different from a *IoC container* as the latter handles instanciation and provides a service locator (i.e. `val x = IoC.resolve<IMyDependency>()`); since a *DI container* does not require the concrete services to know that a *DI container* exists at all, they cannot be the same concept.

  - This would be my understanding when reading questions and answers from StackOverflow

Can you clear that confusion?

Comment: One can take one of a few stances on this, but the bottom line, as I see it, is that most people aren't particularly precise in the way that they use words like that. Lots of people use *IoC* and *DI* as synonyms, which also carries over to *IoC Container* versus *DI Container*. I've never heard that these should be two separate concepts. For Fowler's differentiation between *IoC* and *DI*, though, see my answer in the question marked as the duplicate. If you feel that doesn't properly address your question, then please let me know.