# Accessing strongly typed configuration settings directly into class library in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 application. It has a Data Access library which needs a connection string to make a connection to the database.
Currently I am passing a strongly typed configuration settings class with connection string as a public property all the way up from the MVC controllers (Where it is received through DI) to the Data Access Class library.

I want to know if there is a better way for a class library to access strongly typed configuration settings using dependency injection or any other mechanism ?

Thank you.

EDIT : Code Example

This is a generic DbTransaction class which is called from the business layer.

```
public class DbTransactions<TEntity> where TEntity : DbEntity, new()
{
        private readonly Query _query;

        public DbTransactions(string connectionString)
        {
            _query = new Query(connectionString);
        }

        public TEntity GetById(long id)
        {
            var sqlGenerator = new SqlGenerator<TEntity>();
            var sql = sqlGenerator.GetSelectByIdQuery();
            var mapper = new NMapper.Mapper<TEntity>();
            var cmd = _query.GetNpgsqlCommand(sql, new { id });
            return mapper.GetObject(cmd);
        }
}
```

The query class creates the connection object from the connection string that is provided to it.

Comment: Just inject the `IOptions<T>` in the data access class.

Comment: @HenkMollema: Injecting `IOptions<T>` into your components is [a really bad idea](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/143#issuecomment-155029876).

Comment: Do you create your data access classes in the controller actions? How does the constructors of such classes look like?

Comment: @YacoubMassad No the DataAccess classes are not accessible from the controller actions. There is a business layer that communicates between the Controllers and the DataAccess classes. Data Access classes have no properties just static methods to do CRUD operations. They have nothing on the constructor. Just the default constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @Steven that using `IOptions<T>` is a bad idea. You can however use the `ConfigurationBinder` extensions to read out a specific section of configuration into a strongly-typed POCO class. Just make sure you have this somewhere in your project.json's `dependencies` section:

```
"dependencies": {
    [other dependencies],
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    [other dependencies]
}
```

Just build up your configuration as normal. For example, say you had a Database.json configuration file that looked like this:

```
{
  "Database": {
    "ConnectionInfo": {
      "connectionString": "myConnectionString"
    }
  }
}
```

You can build your configuration from the `Startup` method in Startup.cs:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv) {
  IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
    .AddJsonFile("Database.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
  Configuration = configBuilder.Build();
}
```

Now we can make a POCO class to match the `"Database:ConnectionInfo"` section of the JSON configuraiton file. You can match it to an interface as @janhartmann suggests, but it may or may not be necessary.

```
public class DatabaseConnectionInfo {
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Now, how can we get that `DatabaseConnectionInfo` class populated with the data from the JSON config file? One way is to use the `IOptions<T>` framework type, but I don't like using framework types when I can avoid them. Instead, you can get an instance like so:

```
DatabaseConnectionInfo dbConnInfo = Configuration
  .GetSection("Database:ConnectionInfo")
  .Get<DatabaseConnectionInfo>();
```

Now you can just register the `dbConnInfo` type as a singleton of the type `DatabaseConnectionInfo` (or as a singleton of an interface type if you prefer to have an immutable configuration settings object). Once it's registered in the IoC container, you can constructor inject it where needed:

```
public class DbTransactions<TEntity> where TEntity : DbEntity, new()
{
  private readonly Query _query;

  public DbTransactions(DatabaseConnectionInfo dbConnInfo)
  {
    _query = new Query(dbConnInfo.ConnectionString);
  }

  public TEntity GetById(long id) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let your service class depend on a an interface, e.g.:

```
public interface IConnectionFactory {
    string ConnectionString();
}

public class MyDataAccessClass {

    private readonly IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory

    public MyDataAccessClass(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public void Whatever() {
        var connectionString = _connectionFactory.ConnectionString();
    }

}
```

And then make an implementation of it (as near to your composition root as possible):

```
public class SqlConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory {
     public string ConnectionString() {
        return "myConnectionString";
     }
}
```

Let the interface have the methods or properties you need.

Wire like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IConnectionFactory, SqlConnectionFactory>();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use this method but I am unable to understand what exactly you meant by "as near to your composition root as possible". I did go through some post trying to understand the term and the best explanation I could find was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1410738/2737433). So am I suppose to make an implementation of the IConnectionFactory as close to the startup class as possible ? or am I missing the whole point here ? I am sorry for not being well informed about these concepts.

Comment: If you post your data access code, or class that you need to work with - i can give you a complete example :-)

Comment: I have edited the post to include some code. Let me know if its not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar method to some of those listed earlier, but I think its sufficiently different to warrant another answer.

Firstly I define an interface with all the configuration that my class needs. In this case

```
public interface IDbTransactionsConfiguration {
    string ConnectionString { get; }
}
```

Then I alter my class to take this configuration via constructor injection

```
public class DbTransactions<TEntity> where TEntity : DbEntity, new() {
    public DbTransactions(IDbTransactionsConfiguration configuration) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I define a class that handles all the configuration for my application.

```
public class MyApplicationConfiguration : IDbTransactionsConfiguration, ISomeOtherConfiguration, etc {
    public string ConnectionString { get; }
    ... other configuration
}
```

Then I pass this class into all classes that need it using some kind of Depenendency Injection (normally Castle Windsor or AutoFac for me).

If it is too difficult to construct `DbTransactions` for legacy type reasons, I define a static version of MyApplicationConfiguration and access this directly.

More details on [this blog post](https://medium.com/p/a2706b2d4741).