# Need Clarification about Dependency Inversion Example

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Im trying to understand Dependency Injection.
I have created a sample example for this .
Can any one please tell ,is this example correct or not

```
public interface IEngine
    {
        void Start();
        void SayHelloFromEngine();
    };
    public class Engine :IEngine
    {
        public Engine(){
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            Console.Write ("Hey it is started");
        }
        public void SayHelloFromEngine()
        {
            Console.Write ("Hello from Engine");
        }
    }
    public class Car 
    {
        private readonly IEngine _engine;
        public Car(IEngine engine){
            _engine=engine;
            _engine.SayHelloFromEngine ();
        }

    }
```

and my object creation would be

```
Car car2 = new Car (new Engine ());
```

Please guide me on what steps i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You example looks good to me.  That's pretty much how I tend to structure things.

There is a good stack overflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) with some useful links and posts.

The thing to work on I guess, is how you create the implementations and managing your dependencies. You can create your own factory classes/methods to do it, or use an existing framework, something like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the references

Answer (score 0):

It's common to add a *guard clause* to your constructors that take dependencies, so that you can throw an exception immediately if someone tries to pass in a null dependency.

```
public class Car 
{
   private readonly IEngine _engine;
   public Car(IEngine engine)
   {
      if (engine == null)
      {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("engine");
      }
      _engine=engine;
      _engine.SayHelloFromEngine ();
   }
}
```

A big part of dependency injection is how you create your dependencies.  When you say `Car car2 = new Car (new Engine ());`, you're hard coding your dependency, which is kind of defeating the purpose of dependency injection.  You should have a single [composition root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410719/design-where-should-objects-be-registered-when-using-windsor/1410738#1410738) where all of your dependencies are defined.  If you're not sure whether you're doing something correctly, a good rule of thumb is that you should not be `new`ing any of your dependencies anywhere.

One more thing; when you're composing your dependencies, make sure you don't fall into the trap of making a [service locator.](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)