# ASP.Net Core WebAPI architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating simple WebAPI and I would like to use 3 layer architecture

DAL -> Services -> API

**DAL** - DB context, entityes

**Services** - repositories, services and bussiness logic

**API** - API.Net Core 2 WebAPI

my question is how should I register DB Context into my Dependency Injector?

I have this line of code in **startup.cs**

```
var connectionString = Configuration["connectionStrings:libraryDBConnectionString"];
services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

but **LibraryContext** is placed in DAL project so I have to reference DAL project into my API project.

Is it correct implementation or should I use interface project with **ILibraryContext**?

Comment: Classic DI related question. All projects should be bind in the composition root of the entry project i.e. the api.  You should reference all project to the web project and bind them there. Here's a answer which covers why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401900/bootstrapping-unity-composition-root-location/40403875#40403875

Comment: See [Ioc/DI - Why do I have to reference all layers/assemblies in entry application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application)